# Why is the ArrayList not updated in the following example?

Tags: java

I am using the [`JNativeHook`](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) library.

An instance of `GlobalKeyListener` starts listening to Keystrokes and adds them to `arrayList1`; problem is that the `arrayList1` does not seem to get updated (`list1itemCount` does never get bigger then 0) when accessing it over the infinite `while(true)` loop in the Child class. Why is that and what must I do to achieve that?

```
public class Child {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get the logger for "org.jnativehook" and set the level to warning.
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
        logger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        }
        catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

            System.exit(1);
        }

        GlobalKeyListener globalkeylistener = new GlobalKeyListener();
        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(globalkeylistener);
        Connection conn;
        while(true){
            int list1itemCount = globalkeylistener.arrayList1.size();
            if (list1itemCount >= 4)
                System.out.println(list1itemCount);
        }
    }
}
```

GlobalKeyListener Class:

```
public class GlobalKeyListener implements NativeKeyListener {
    ArrayList<Class1> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Class1> listing() {
        return arrayList1;
    }

    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        arrayList1.add(new Class1(e.getKeyCode(), 1));
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        arrayList1.add(new Class1(e.getKeyCode(), 0));
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `nativeKeyPressed` or `nativeKeyReleased` even get called?

Comment: Your `while(true)` loop will be spinning hard with no pauses.  Maybe add a `Thread.sleep(100);` or a wait/notify so that the GlobalKeyListener can get some cycles?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes nativeKeyPressed and nativeKeyReleased do get called I checked with System.out.println.

Comment: @schtever Thread polling is not really a good idea.

Comment: @theV0ID This is an MCVE, he just didn't mention what library he was using; I have edited the post to include that information.

Comment: Thread.sleep() did made it update thx!

Comment: @durron597: Pardon me. Now it makes sense. :)

Comment: @JCD: The `sleep` doesn't *fix* your problem, at best it *hides* it in some cases. You better stick to durron's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multithreading issue. The `keyEvent` updates occur on a different thread, and your `while(true)` won't update. Also, the `ArrayList` itself is not threadsafe as you've written it.

It would be better to synchronize on something (the easiest, not necessarily best) thing is the key listener itself, and have it wait until the update occurs and then notify. Here's the modified code:

#### GlobalKeyListener.java

```
public class GlobalKeyListener implements NativeKeyListener {
  ArrayList<Class1> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
  public ArrayList<Class1> listing() {
      return arrayList1;
  }

  public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    synchronized(this) {
      arrayList1.add(new Class1(e.getKeyCode(), 1));
      this.notifyAll();
    }
  }

  public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    synchronized(this) {
      arrayList1.add(new Class1(e.getKeyCode(), 0));
      this.notifyAll();
    }
  }

  public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
  }
}
```

#### Child.java

```
public class Child {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
    logger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
      try {
          GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
      }
      catch (NativeHookException ex) {
          System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
          System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

          System.exit(1);
      }

      GlobalKeyListener globalkeylistener = new GlobalKeyListener();
      GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(globalkeylistener);
      synchronized(globalkeylistener) {
        while(true){
            int list1itemCount = globalkeylistener.arrayList1.size();
            if (list1itemCount >= 4) {
                System.out.println(list1itemCount);
            }
            globalkeylistener.wait();
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does look really good, that seems to be the underlying issue. I will study your answer in detail and eventually mark it as correct. Thank You!